# Bug on Chrome while implementing gconnect module in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

i'm using this module to connect from Gmail to my site, it's working greate on firefox but on chrome the button (Sign in Using Google) is not appearing..

if i go to console, i found a javascript error on the file:

```
(http://localhost/mysite/sites/all/modules/gconnect/git-for-drupal.js?o) on the line 6:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```

Also i am getting an error in `Importer.js on line 2035: uncaught syntaxerror unexpected` identifier

Please help in solving this issue, http://drupal.org/node/1807348

Answer (score 0):

It happens in my drupal and i installed a Jquery update module link below, and change my jquery version it works great. I think default drupal jquery version is 1.4.

https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Also if you need use jquery's Browser function you have to add extra js to your file.

jQuery.browser() removed
The jQuery.browser() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. If you still need this function, you can get one js file from: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin and link the js to your file.